# SIGBART in C code with malloc/free

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I wrote this small program to find all occurrences of a substring in a larger string, or a *needle* in a *haystack*. When I run the program locally, it seems to work just fine. However, when I submit it to an online contest for judging, it gives a SIGBART error. I assumed it was because of poor memory-management, so I deleted the `free()` function calls, but then I got a *Time Limit Exceeded* error (but the SIGBART error disappeared). Does removing the `free()` calls slow the program? And are there any leaks in my program?

Here the contest I was talking about:
[Needle in the Haystack](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/NHAY/)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RAW_INPUT_SIZE 10000

#define BOOL unsigned int
#define NO 0
#define YES 1

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   int needleLength;
   char *rawNeedle = (char *)malloc(RAW_INPUT_SIZE);
   char *rawHaystack = (char *)malloc(RAW_INPUT_SIZE);
   char *needle; // to be allocated later
   char *haystack; // to be allocated later, but not deallocated
   while (scanf("%i\n%s\n%s", &needleLength, rawNeedle, rawHaystack) != EOF)
   {
      needle = (char *)malloc(needleLength);
      strncpy(needle, rawNeedle, needleLength);
      haystack = strchr(rawHaystack, needle[0]);
      int i = haystack - rawHaystack;
      BOOL matchesFound = NO;
      if (i + needleLength - 1 < strlen(rawHaystack))
      {
         while (haystack != NULL)
         {
            if (i + needleLength - 1 < strlen(rawHaystack))
            {
               char *substr = (char *)malloc(needleLength);
               strncpy(substr, haystack, needleLength);
               if (strcmp(needle, substr) == 0)
               {
                  printf("%i\n", i);
                  matchesFound = YES;
               }
               free(substr);
               substr = NULL;
            }
            haystack = strchr(haystack+1, needle[0]);
            i = haystack - rawHaystack;
         }
      }
      if (matchesFound == NO)
         printf("\n");
      free(needle);
      needle = NULL;
   }
   free(rawNeedle);
   free(rawHaystack);
   rawNeedle = NULL;
   rawHaystack = NULL;
   return 0;
}
```

---

Transcription of input and output specification from the question

> #### Input
>
> The input consists of a number of test cases. Each test case is composed of three lines, containing:
>
> - the length of the needle,
> - the needle itself,
> - the haystack.
>
> The length of the needle is only limited by the memory available to your program, so do not make any assumptions - instead, read the length and allocate memory as needed. The haystack is not limited in size, which implies that your program should not read the whole haystack at once. The KMP algorithm is stream-based, i.e. it processes the haystack character by character, so this is not a problem.
>
> The test cases come one after another, each occupying three lines, with no additional space or line breaks in between.
>
> #### Output
>
> For each test case your program should output all positions of the needle's occurences within the haystack. If a match is found, the output should contain the position of the first character of the match. Characters in the haystack are numbered starting with zero.
>
> For a given test case, the positions output should be sorted in ascending order, and each of these should be printed in a separate line. For two different test cases, the positions should be separated by an empty line.

Comment: Make sure your strings are null-terminated. Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to zero out the new memory. Don't cast the result of *alloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use any memory allocation?  If the specification includes a maximum needle length of 10,000, simply use local arrays:

```
char needle[RAW_INPUT_SIZE];
char haystack[RAW_INPUT_SIZE];
```

Read directly into these; don't copy them around.

```
char *substr = (char *)malloc(needleLength);
strncpy(substr, haystack, needleLength);
if (strcmp(needle, substr) == 0)
```

It is not clear that your needle length includes the trailing null.  Therefore, this does not allocate enough space and does not guarantee null termination, both of which can easily lead to SIGABRT problems.

Repeatedly using `strlen()` on your haystack will make your program run slowly.  You can calculate the lengths without needing to do `strlen()` more than once on each of the needle and haystack.

Unless you are guaranteed no blanks in the data, your `scanf()` code will read less than you expect.  You should always check that you get all the values you expect.

You should look up the function `strstr()`.

Comment: The contest also says that the strings will be as large as memory allows, how would I initialize them to that length?

Comment: You will have to allocate the correct amount of space for the needle and then read that into memory (probably not using `scanf()`, I suggest; `fgets()` is probably appropriate, but you'll have to delete the newline).  Then, for the haystack, you will have to read the input line in segments.  Superficially, you need to be able to allocate a needle's worth of data at a time; things get mind-bending if you can only have part of the needle's worth of haystack in memory (so, for example, if the needle is 20KiB but you only have 10KiB of haystack in memory, then the search gets tricky).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the direct cause of your problem, but one obvious issue is that you're not using `strncpy` correct.  `strncpy` does not necessarily NUL-terminate.

Also, you don't check if `malloc` succeeds, nor do you check if `strchr` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting crucial memory.

> The length of the needle is only limited by the memory available to your program, so do not make any assumptions - instead, read the length and allocate memory as needed. The haystack is not limited in size, which implies that your program should not read the whole haystack at once. The KMP algorithm is stream-based, i.e. it processes the haystack character by character, so this is not a problem.

You can count on some inputs being longer than 10000 `char`s. That means you're using unallocated memory, with unpredictable consequences.

More predictable is that - as already mentioned by Jonathan Leffler - your `substr` will generally not be 0-terminated, so the `strcmp` can only return 0 if perchance `substr` is immediately followed by a '\0' character, thus you're likely to miss occurrences of `needle` in `haystack` (and likely to clobber haystack in the course of your algorithm).

And your algorithm is the naive algorithm (somewhat enhanced by scanning specifically for the first character of `needle`), that is probably too slow:

> However, a naive approach will probably exceed the time limit, whereas other algorithms are more complicated... The choice is yours.

You should for each test case

1. read the length of the needle
2. allocate enough space for the needle (including the 0-terminator)
3. read in the needle
4. read in the haystack in chunks, interleaved with scanning for the needle

SPOJ recommends using the KMP algorithm, not without reason. Using the Boyer-Moore algorithm is a good alternative, but makes handling matches that cross chunk boundaries more complicated.